# I need to work out probability on a draw of 16 players (I am not a math fundi .. but i have a good grasp of the fundamentals)

Tags: probability, descriptive-statistics, statistical-mechanics

I read this site all the time for solutions to problems at work, but I cant find anything that quite applies to this problem

There is currently an african snooker championship taking place in Egypt (6 reds) and there were 3 saffas (south africans like me) who made it through to the last 16. So for the purposes of this calculation we must also allow for seedings, which 1 saffa made from what i understand..

In brief: 3 of 16 players ended up in the same quadrant(i.e. 4 places playing to a top 8 spot in the knockout stages) of the draw, with one player being a seeded saffa (assuming there are 8 seeds). What is the probability and statistical likelihood (with all the bells and deviations you can throw at me) of this happening in a random draw for all 16 places please?

I had no idea where to start with this.. but using some game theory i tried $n(n-1)(n-2)/10000$ - so I used the $25%$ for a quadrant and came up with 1.38% .. yes yes this is black magic math to you bright guys probably, but I was lost ok, so I am here now..

I know that in other major comps the saffas could not be drawn against their seeded fellow countryman, but that is a different fight and post altogether.

Comment: How can there be $4$ quadrants if there are $8$ seeds? This seems to imply that several seeds will end up in the same quadrant, which contradicts the definition of seed, doesn't it?

Comment: Maybe let me word it this way: is there a restriction on who can end up with who (possibly because of the seeds)?

Comment: So in a knockout or cup competition it stacks as follows
1 plays 2, 3 plays 4, 5 plays 6, till 16..follow?
The quadrants are 2 of these matches in the round of 16.
So 1 plays 2 and 3 plays 4. 
The winners of these matches will face one another in the next knockout round or round of 8, which means only one will go through to the semi-final or round of 4. 

This was our issue in that how is possible for 3 south africans to end up there, meaning only one possible saffa could make the semi-final even.

Answer (score 1):

The question has many terms which I do not understand (some of which was asked in the comments), however here is my interpretation:

There are four quadrants, and the seeded player must land in one of them.  There are three other places in that quadrant, and twelve places not in that quadrant.  We now place the two other saffa players in these 15 places.  There are ${3\choose 2}=3$ ways to place them in that same quadrant with the seeded player, and ${15\choose 2}=105$ ways to place them among $15$ places.  Hence, if the nonseeded players are placed at random, there is a probability of $$\frac{3}{105}\approx 2.9\%$$
that they will both be placed together with the seeded player.

Comment: thank you very much, apologies for the rhetoric in the original question btw.

Your answer is surprisingly simple and is definitely one I needed. 
However we need to take it one step further. 

Can we work out the stats/probability(not sure of the right term) of all 3 saffas ending up in the same quadrant in a random draw. Lets ignore the seeding for this.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You should ask this as a separate question.

Comment: Ok thank you. I will do if it becomes necessary. I appreciate you helping me understand how to go about solving the problem.